# bind FORMERR but dig works fine (CNAME => DNAME)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I do some interesting things with DNS, as [many others](https://labs.spotify.com/2017/03/31/spotifys-lovehate-relationship-with-dns/) do, but this one is puzzling.

I have an abstraction layer in dns to make customer facing records consistent and independent of backend infrastructure, part of this is the ability to flip and entire zone with 1 record change, for this we use DNAMEs

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
record.example.com. IN CNAME record.alias.example.net.
@ IN NS ns.example.com.
ns.example.com. IN A 192.168.1.10

$ORIGIN example.net.
alias IN DNAME real_site
record.real_site IN CNAME server-name.example.org.
@ IN NS ns.example.com.

$ORIGIN example.org.
server-name.example.org. IN A 192.168.1.1
@ IN NS ns.example.com.
```

for some reason, I can DIG record.example.com. and receive A record 192.168.1.1 on the nameservers for example.com.

**DIG Output**

```
dig @192.168.1.10 record.example.com.
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;record.example.com.         IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
record.example.com.  600     IN      CNAME   record.alias.example.net.
alias.example.net. 300 IN      DNAME   real_site.example.net.
record.alias.example.net. 300 IN  CNAME   record.real_site.example.net.
record.real_site.example.net. 300 IN CNAME server-name.example.org.
server-name.example.org. 300 IN A       192.168.1.1
```

BUT I cannot query via my local bind dns server with the same request.

**Bind Errors:**

```
named-pkcs11[8613]: error (FORMERR) resolving 'record.example.com/A/IN': 192.168.1.10#53
```

**Bind Version**

```
named-pkcs11 -v
BIND 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3 (Extended Support Version)
```

Comment: Mandatory question: did you try with newer bind versions? In release notes of 9.10 there are various points about DNAME handling… Also I hope that the underscore in real_site is just an example and not really there?

Comment: yeah no underscores in host names. I haven't tried a newer version yet I will see if it's available for the version I need for freeipa.

Comment: Trying another resolver, such as `unbound` may help pinpoint if the problem is with the zone content or the software doing the query.